# Unable to output values in the required format using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, format, printf, echo

I need to output an array to a file in the following format.

```
File: a.txt
      b.txt
```

I tried doing the following  :

```
declare -a files=("a.txt" "b.txt")
empty=""
printf "File:" >> files.txt
for i in "${files[@]}"
do 
   printf "%-7s %-30s \n" "$empty" "$i" >> files.txt
done
```

But, I get the output as

```
 File: a.txt
 b.txt
```

Can anyone please help me to get the output in the required format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

files=( 'a.txt' 'b.txt' 'c.txt' 'd.txt' )

set -- "${files[@]}"

printf 'File: %s\n' "$1"
shift
printf '      %s\n' "$@"
```

Output:

```
File: a.txt
      b.txt
      c.txt
      d.txt
```

This uses the fact that `printf` will reuse its formatting string for all its other command line parameters.

We set the positional parameters to the list and then output the first element with the `File:` string prepended.  We then shift `$1` off the list of positional parameters and print the rest with a spacer string inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a files=("a.txt" "b.txt")

for i in "${files[@]}"
do
   echo "$i" >> files.txt
done
sed -i '1 s/^/File: /' files.txt
sed -i '1 ! s/^/      /' files.txt
```

If you are using Mac, you have to modify `sed` commands in this way

```
sed -i '' '1 s/^/File: /' files.txt
sed -i '' '1 ! s/^/      /' files.txt
```

The output will be:

```
File: a.txt
      b.txt
```

First of all we put into txt file all the file names (`for loop`). After that, via first `sed` command we add `File:` to the first line and via second `sed` command we add to all lines, except the first, six spaces equal to length of string `File:`

Answer (score 0):

You could always started with a variable containing `File:` for the first iteration, and overwrite it with the correct number of spaces each time. The repeated assignment won't induce too much overhead.

```
prefix="File:"

for i in "${files[@]}"
do 
   printf "%-7s %-30s \n" "$prefix" "$i"
   prefix=
done > Files.txt
```